# Facebook share button for each image in a WordPress post

Tags: facebook, wordpress, post, share

I want run a contest. In this contest, I want say "please choose your favourite image." Every image should have their own Facebook share button. The button should share only the image, not the complete url.

I tried the like- and send buttons from Facebook, and it works okay, but if F click like and F put a comment it only publishes the link to the image and not the image itself. Also, it is only published to my Facebook wall if I put a comment. If I only click like, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest solution is to use the structure

Make sure to read this to specify the thumbnail you want: http://grafikdesign.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/facebook-sharespecifying-meta-tags-fbml-audio-flash-video-action-bar/